# Pass html message as parameter in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, jq

I am trying to pass

```
jq '.text.message="<p style=text-align: left; font-size: 14px><font color=\"#1a1a1a\"><b>Test</b></font> </p>"'
```

but it's not accepting HTML.
how to pass HTML as a message by using jq

Comment: What are you trying to do for real ? Extract some HTML part ? jq is not for HTML but JSON

Answer (score 0):

(not an answer, but a formatted comment)

What's the problem you're having? This works fine:

```sh
echo '{"text": {"message": "some message here"}}' |
  jq '.text.message="<p style=text-align: left; font-size: 14px><font color=\"#1a1a1a\"><b>Test</b></font> </p>"'
```

outputs

```
{
  "text": {
    "message": "<p style=text-align: left; font-size: 14px><font color=\"#1a1a1a\"><b>Test</b></font> </p>"
  }
}
```

---

Here's one way to do it that avoids any need to escape the "inner" double quotes:

```sh
html='<![CDATA[ <p style="text-align: left; font-size: 14px; color: #4d4d4d; line-height: 18px;"><font color="#1a1a1a"><b>test</b></font> - <font color="#4d4d4d">Hello </font></p> <p style="text-align: left; font-size: 14px; color: #4d4d4d; line-height: 18px;"><font color="#1a1a1a"><b>test</b></font> - <font color="#4d4d4d">Hi </font></p> ]]>'

# pass the shell variable into jq with the --arg option:
echo '{"text": {"message": "some message here"}}' | jq --arg msg "$html" '.text.message = $msg'
```

```
{
  "text": {
    "message": "<![CDATA[ <p style=\"text-align: left; font-size: 14px; color: #4d4d4d; line-height: 18px;\"><font color=\"#1a1a1a\"><b>test</b></font> - <font color=\"#4d4d4d\">Hello </font></p> <p style=\"text-align: left; font-size: 14px; color: #4d4d4d; line-height: 18px;\"><font color=\"#1a1a1a\"><b>test</b></font> - <font color=\"#4d4d4d\">Hi </font></p> ]]>"
  }
}
```

Comment: i want to se message = <![CDATA[
    <p style="text-align: left; font-size: 14px; color: #4d4d4d; line-height: 18px;"><font color="#1a1a1a"><b>test</b></font> - <font color="#4d4d4d">Hello </font></p>
  <p style="text-align: left; font-size: 14px; color: #4d4d4d; line-height: 18px;"><font color="#1a1a1a"><b>test</b></font> - <font color="#4d4d4d">Hi </font></p>
]]>

Comment: jq: error: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 2:

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your input is, or what your expected output is, but one reading of the question is that there is no input.
In that case, the answer is: use the -n command-line option:

```
$ jq -n '.text.message="<p style=text-align: left; font-size: 14px><font color=\"#1a1a1a\"><b>Test</b></font> </p>"'
```

#### Output

```
{
  "text": {
    "message": "<p style=text-align: left; font-size: 14px><font color=\"#1a1a1a\"><b>Test</b></font> </p>"
  }
}
```

### "Can we pass complex HTML?"

Here are illustrations of three approaches:

```
jq -R '. as $in | ({} | .text.message=$in)' <<< "$data"
```

```
jq -R '{text: {message: .}}'  <<< "$data"
```

```
jq -n --arg data "$data" '.text.message=.'
```

For testing, you can use your example:

```
data='<![CDATA[ <p style="text-align: left; font-size: 14px; color: #4d4d4d; line-height: 18px;"><font color="#1a1a1a"><b>test</b></font> - <font color="#4d4d4d">Hello </font></p> <p style="text-align: left; font-size: 14px; color: #4d4d4d; line-height: 18px;"><font color="#1a1a1a"><b>test</b></font> - <font color="#4d4d4d">Hi </font></p> ]]>'
```

Comment: can we pass complex html ?

Comment: <![CDATA[
    <p style="text-align: left; font-size: 14px; color: #4d4d4d; line-height: 18px;"><font color="#1a1a1a"><b>test</b></font> - <font color="#4d4d4d">Hello </font></p>
  <p style="text-align: left; font-size: 14px; color: #4d4d4d; line-height: 18px;"><font color="#1a1a1a"><b>test</b></font> - <font color="#4d4d4d">Hi </font></p>
]]>